# Trouble registering with Freeswitch server

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have Windows on which I am running Ubuntu on VM. I have installed free-switch in Ubuntu. I am having difficulty in registering my softphone (on my mobile) with Free-switch and am using wired internet connection.

I think this has got something to do with Network settings; I tried NAT, bridge etc. But nothing has worked out for me till now

Comment: Is your phone connected to the host computer and you are trying to have the vm communicate with it that way?

Comment: Actually, I have WIFI router over which I am connecting the phone. But my PC doesnt support WIFI. Hence using wired connection for PC. Also, I am registering to the VM (as freeswitch is installed on VM).

Comment: After connecting the phone, the IP address of phone is 192 series and so is VM's.